# MVC3 C# ViewModel on Postback for saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, postback, save, viewmodel

I have this certain viewmodel with viewmodels and collections. When I click save button that invokes postback, I can't get the viewmodels and collections inside the viewmodel. I need to declare viewmodels and collections in the parameter of the function in able to get it. Is there a way to get the viewmodel complete with it's viewmodels and collections?

I have this Customer viewModel

```
public class CustomerViewModel 
{ 
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public PersonInfoViewModel PersonInfoViewModel { get; set; } 
   public ICollection<PurchasesViewModel> PurchasesViewModel { get; set; } 
}
```

when I try to postback in my controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult New(FormCollection collection, CustomerViewModel customerViewModel, PersonInfoViewModel personInfoViewModel, ICollection<PurchasesViewModel> purchasesViewModel) 
{ 
   customerViewModel.PersonInfoViewModel = personInfoViewModel; 
   ... 
}
```

I forgot to mention that the ViewModels and Collections are rendered using partial views. Thanks

Comment: Can you please post some controller and view code so I can more specifically see what you're talking about?

Comment: I have this Customer viewModel

public class CustomerViewModel
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public PersonInfoViewModel PersonInfoViewModel { get; set; }
 public ICollection<PurchasesViewModel> PurchasesViewModel { get; set; }
}

when I try to postback in my controller:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(FormCollection collection, CustomerViewModel customerViewModel, PersonInfoViewModel personInfoViewModel, ICollection<PurchasesViewModel> purchasesViewModel)
{
 customerViewModel.PersonInfoViewModel = personInfoViewModel;
 ...
}

Comment: @Badz, you should really have edited your original question and put the code in there. It is near unreadable as a comment

Comment: Badz-- If you are using FormCollection in your controller's POST method, you shouldn't have those other objects in its signature. If you want to go with just your main "CustomerViewModel" (which looks like it contains the other other viewmodel -- PersonInfoViewModel, etc), just have the CustomerViewModel in the controller signature. That being said, I think that your View must also be strongly typed to your CustomerViewModel.

Comment: My view is strongly typed, And I'm using FormCollection to determine what button the user clicks(there are 2 buttons, 1 is save, 2 is preview). I forgot to mention that I'm rendering the viewmodels and collections in some partial views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use RenderPertial for the rendering of a ViewModel in Viewmodel.

You have to use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchasesViewModel)`

Then make a folder named `EditorTemplates`, either in the shared folder or in the folder you're surfing.

Next you have to create a view in that folder with the ViewModels name. So in your situation you have to make a view called `PurchasesViewModel`

Comment: Is that different from @Html.Partial? I'm using this one on my views.

Comment: Partial views can be used for anything, it doesn't require a model. So for example you could use a partial for a small text that comes back a lot of the times. 

While EditorFor requires a Model and can't be used without.

Comment: I'll try your solution, then will reply and mark as answer once proved to be the solution thanks